# How to get error detail when transaction aborted

Tags: c#, transactions

I am using `System.Transanction` and the `TransanctionCompleted` event to detect aborted transactions.

How do I find out why it failed? Is a way to detect the error details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch [System.Transactions.TransactionException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionexception.aspx) on your transaction method

```
try
{
    //Create the transaction scope
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Register for the transaction completed event for the current transaction
        Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Current_TransactionCompleted);
        // proces the transaction
    }

}
catch (System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
catch (System.Transactions.TransactionException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot complete transaction");
    throw;
}
```

Transaction completed event handler

```
static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A transaction has completed:");
    Console.WriteLine("ID:             {0}", e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.LocalIdentifier);
    Console.WriteLine("Distributed ID: {0}", e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier);
    Console.WriteLine("Status:         {0}", e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status);
    Console.WriteLine("IsolationLevel: {0}", e.Transaction.IsolationLevel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I meant get error details inside the transaction completed event, since I only have access to the transaction but it is not up to my code to determine if to commit/abort the transaction or not. Thanks again.

Comment: you have to do it on TransactionScope calling method.